# How do I split a SQL table into two, referencing the new table's ID in the original table?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

My company has a table in SQL that holds all our quote information. Up until now, our quote # was also our internal product #, i.e. all product information was stored with the quote. Obviously, this isn't the best practice, so we are now restructuring such that we have a separate product and quote table. Among other things, this will enable us to have multiple quotes per product. I have already created the new product table; however, I need to do the following:

1. Move product data (such as dimensions, features, materials, etc.) from existing quotes in the the quote table to new product lines in the product table
2. For each row of data transferred from the quote table to the product table, I need to return the Product No (the product's primary ID, automatically incremented in SQL) from the new row created in the product table and insert that Product No to the record in the quote table from which that data originated
3. Delete the columns in the quote table that have now been moved to the product table

Existing data structure (one "Quote" table)

| Quote No | Customer | Product Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | John Doe | 10 x 10 x 10 |
| 67890 | Jane Doe | 20 x 30 x 40 |

New data structure (one "Quote" table, one "Product" table")

| Quote No | Product No | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | John Doe |
| 67890 | 2 | Jane Doe |

| Product No | Product Size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 x 10 x 10 |
| 2 | 20 x 30 x 40 |

Two notes:

- The reason I need both a Product No and a Quote No is because, as I mentioned, we may have the same product assigned to multiple quotes
- There are hundreds of existing quotes, so when I split this table, it is very important that these quotes correctly reference the new product number such that they are properly linked to the right product information.

I'm thinking something like this for the query... (Note: I am working in SSMS to write the query)

```
INSERT INTO [Product] ([Product Size])
     OUTPUT INSERTED.[Product No]
     INTO [Quote] ([Product No])
SELECT [Product Size]
FROM [Quote]
```

But, as I said, I need to be sure that the new Product No is correctly inserted into the quote table, e.g. Product No "2" doesn't get inserted into Quote No "12345"

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - your existing table doesn't have a product number (or anything relevant to a product, apart from its size) so I'm not sure what you mean by "current Product No"?

Comment: @NickW That's a good point - sorry, that should say "the new Product No". I will update the original post to reflect this correction.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, oracle, mysql, postgres, etc)?

Comment: For speed and Ease I would populate the product table and then update the Quotes Table Product No by doing an UPDATE with INNER JOIN to Product on Product Size.  I know joins on varchar is poor for performance, but for a script I'm running as a one time thing I'd take the hit.

Comment: @JNevill I am writing the query in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @Dizzy I'm not sure this would guarantee that the Quotes Table receives the proper Product No (although I could just be misunderstanding your meaning). How would this ensure that Quote No "12345" gets assigned to Product No "1", instead of, for example, Product No "2"?

Comment: @Leah because you’ll be joining on the Product Size, see my answer for how you do this

Answer (score 0):

A couple of caveats, I'm going to assume *Product Size* is a *varchar* for this.  I'm also going to assume that your product sizes in the **Quote** table are formatted to a similar standard and are as clean as possible. For example "***1x1x1***" and "***1 x 1 x 1***" are ***not*** to a similar standard and will be treated as separate products, if you need to fix these then I suggest addressing that first.

**To answer your question**, I would do this in stages.

First create your **Product** table (with auto incrementing **Product No**/ID) and add the new column for **Product No**(nullable) in **Quote**

Then populate it with all the unique product Sizes from the **Quote**

```
INSERT Product([Product Size])
SELECT DISTINCT([Product Size]) from Quote
```

Next update the **Product No** in **Quote** using an INNER JOIN.

```
UPDATE Quote
SET [Product No] = p.[Product No]
FROM Quote q
INNER JOIN Product p ON q.[Product Size] = p.[Product Size]
```

Check you're happy with the data before going further.

Now you can remove the **Product Size** column from **Quote**, add a foreign key constraint on **Product No** and make it **not null** too.